# LongListSelector with separator between the rows

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have this LongListSelector:

```
<Controls:LongListSelector x:Name="searchList" Margin="0,0,0,0"  Background="White" SelectionChanged="DidPressSelectSearchList" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" KeyDown="UserPressEnterKeyBoard">
                <Controls:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <local:SearchTemplateSelector Content="{Binding}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                            <local:SearchTemplateSelector.GoogleSuggestTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Rectangle Height="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Fill="Black" Opacity="0.3"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="25" Foreground="Black" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,10"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </local:SearchTemplateSelector.GoogleSuggestTemplate>

                            <local:SearchTemplateSelector.VideoTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Rectangle Height="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Fill="Black" Opacity="0.3"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="25" Foreground="Black" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,10"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                                </local:SearchTemplateSelector.VideoTemplate>
                    </local:SearchTemplateSelector>
                    </DataTemplate>
</Controls:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
```

So when i select the GoogleSuggestTemplate i get this one(And as you can see the separator is until the end of the row):[image]

and when i use VideoTemplate(As you can see the separator is cut before the end):
[image]

any idea why it happen?

Comment: Ok this is no answer to your question, but the design guideline for windows phone states not to use actual Search buttons, but add an InputScope to the textbox you are using... for search that is: InputScope="Search"

Comment: Have you solved your problem?